# cmake: ExternalProject_Add() does not apply cmake arguments

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, cmake

I have troubles while building an external library (glfw) in my cmake file:

```
[...]

ExternalProject_Add(glfw
    PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/glfw"
    URL "https://github.com/glfw/glfw/releases/download/3.2.1/glfw-3.2.1.zip"
    URL_HASH SHA256=b7d55e13e07095119e7d5f6792586dd0849c9fcdd867d49a4a5ac31f982f7326
    CMAKE_ARGS "-DGLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DGLFW_BUILD_TESTS=OFF"
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    TEST_COMMAND ""
)

add_executable(test main.cpp)
add_dependencies(test glfw)
```

Although this works quite well, the given cmake arguments `-DGLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DGLFW_BUILD_TESTS=OFF` are ignored.

According to the [glfw documentation](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/compile.html) the arguments should disable building examples and tests. I only want to build the library (target: glfw).

If I try to build the library separately

```
cmake -DGLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DGLFW_BUILD_TESTS=OFF
```

then it works as expected.

I also study the [cmake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) but I can't get any further.

Am I doing something wrong? Can you choose which target to build or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter `CMAKE_ARGS` contains a **list** of options, NOT a **single string** with *space-separated* options. Correct:

```
CMAKE_ARGS -DGLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DGLFW_BUILD_TESTS=OFF
```

Comment: That works pretty well! Thanks. I thought a string and a "list" would be the same in this situation. But once again learned something new.